# How to call queryAll method

Tags: python, sqlobject

I was going through the instructions specified under [SQL statements](http://sqlobject.org/SQLBuilder.html#sql-statements), and I got stuck at this line:

```
rows = connection.queryAll(query)
```

From where are we getting this connection object? Because I am sure this is not the object obtained from this statement

```
connection = connectionForURI(connection_string)
```

I also tried using dbconnection like this:

```
select = Select(['name', 'AVG(salary)'], staticTables=['employees'], groupBy='name')
query = dbconnection.sqlrepr(select)
```

But dbconnection doesn't have queryAll method.

Comment: The example uses a wildcard import "from sqlobject.sqlbuilder import *". You can check if connection object is among the imports with "print locals()".

Comment: Well no luck, it isn't listed on running print(locals()) with this import

Comment: Well, means that developers got their documentation wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`connection = connectionForURI(connection_string)` is exactly the connection object you're looking for. It [has](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/blob/master/sqlobject/dbconnection.py#L445) method `queryAll`.